# Best way to call two web services from method without blocking each other

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3

I have an MVC3 application and in one of my actions in my controllers I need to reach out to two different web services for data.

The results of one does not depend on the other, so ideally I would like to call out to each of these services in parallel so that I do not incur a performance penalty of waiting for the first before I execute the other.

Together they can (and should) certainly block the action from returning until both web services return their data as their responses should both be sent back in the ActionResult payload.

Comment: BTW, there's no need to start your title with "C#". That's what tags are for.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

HttpWebRequest allows you to send the web service requests asynchronously, but those methods use callbacks, so they won't block after your two requests are kicked off.

To wait for both callbacks, you could wrap each call as a Task and then fire off both tasks in parallel using synchronous http calls.  You'd then use a WaitAll that would wait for both tasks to finish.  The benefit of this is that WaitAll and Task make it easy to implement a timeout, whereas with asynchronous requests it can be a challenge to handle timeouts.

I'm on a mobile now, so I can't grab the code, but this site looks like a good starting point.

[.NET Task Goodness](http://codingndesign.com/blog/?p=202)

Remember, pass your http function in to the Task constructor.  Once both tasks are created, add them to a List.  Your WaitAll will use this list to check for completion.

If you don't like using the synchronous http calls, you could create a thread safe counter that is incremented in the asynchronous callback functions.  Your controller would then sit in a while loop waiting for a timeout or for the counter to equal two.

I guess you could also use an asynchronous controller for my first answer which would still use multiple-threaded sync calls, but the asynchronous controller would free the operation from the processor.

Comment: NET Task Goodness is a broken link

Answer (score 3):

You may find [this article](http://www.csharp-examples.net/create-asynchronous-method/) on creating asynchronous methods in C# helpful.

Can we assume though, that what you're more interested in, is how you can make sure that regardless of which call takes longer to return, you block until you have them both back?

Comment: Well, in that case, you should be able to do what gordy suggested so succintly. It doesn't really matter which one you make async because you have to wait for both of them regardless. You should be able to make the async one set an indication that it has returned and block on the other one until it has returned and the indicator for the first one has been set. Does that make sense?

Comment: Despite his brevity, clearly gordy is more knowledgeable about this subject than I. You should listen to him.

Comment: Thanks, that does make sense and is pretty much what I a looking for.

Answer (score 1):

Create a pair of WaitHandles, call both methods async passing in a wait handle, clear each one in their respective result handlers, use WaitHandle.WaitAll to block until both handles are cleared.

Comment: This would work.  WaitAny waits while any handles exist.  You'd then setup a timeout and wait for either the handles to clear or for the timeout.  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/27y100eh.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Since you need to call two services async I would recommend to use TPL (Task Parllel Library)

```
Parallel.Invoke(
    () => result1 = CallServer1(),
    () => result2 = CallServer2());
```

Here is an example on how to user [TPL](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd992634.aspx) I've done it and works fine.